# tdlib-ruby Telegram API returns Error timed out

Tags: ruby, telegram, tdlib

I was trying to set up a web client for telegram using ruby. I registered for telegram application and obtained **api_id** and **api_hash** keys. Then I am using tdlib with the help of https://github.com/southbridgeio/tdlib-ruby. Each method call returns promise object and when checked for reason, shows - `<TD::Types::Error code=0 message="Timeout error">`. I'm not sure what is wrong. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Had similar problem. You need to connect first. For example:

```
client = TD::Client.new
client.connect.then do
    client.join_chat(chat_id)
end
```

Or

```
client = TD::Client.new
client.connect.wait
client.join_chat(chat_id).wait
```